# PInvoke marshalling of wchar_t parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke, if I have a parameter of type `wchar_t` in a C++ function I need to "decorate it with Unicode".  However, the `MarshalAs` attribute doesn't seem to have any option for this.  The `UnmanagedType` enum in `System.Runtime.InteropServices` doesn't have a `Unicode` element.  Or `Ansi` for that matter, either, though the page suggests that it should.

So, how is this done?

**Edit**

Suppose I had a function that looked like this:

```
int doSomething(wchar_t charIn) { ... }
```

or even

```
int doSomethingElse(wchar_t *charArr) {...}
```

taking an array of `wchar_t` values.  According to the page I should annotate (decorate) these parameters with Unicode.  How would I do this?

Comment: Knowing how your function looks like would be very useful...

Comment: `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` in the `DllImport` attribute constructor. Or `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` on the parameter using `MarshalAs`. Countless examples. Search harder.

Comment: I saw the `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`.  That doesn't help with a single `wchar_t` as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, are you saying, then, that I can't use a mix of `wchar_t` and `char` in the parameter list?

Comment: Pass that as `char` with the character set as I showed. Seriously, a bit more research will get you a long way.

Comment: A single `char` is an oddity really in pinvoke. What's matching on the C# side? There isn't really a matching type. Anyway, that's not what you asked. Did you ask the right question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, according to the docs on the link I have in the question, System.Char is a blittable type and corresponds to **both** `char` and `wchar_t`.  The first should be 'decorated' with Ansi and the second with Unicode.  I just don't see how to do that.

Comment: With CharSet. But why do you want to pass a single AnsiChar? I bet that you don't.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am providing an infrastructure (.NET Core) that will sometimes have to interact with user-provided low-level (native/unmanaged) code.  I am documenting for the end users how to interface their code to the infrastructure.  Their low-level code is often **very** low level and a single char or byte parameter (or `wchar_t`) isn't far fetched at all for this environment.

Comment: What will these users have on the C# side? What type will they be using there? Think about the character encoding implications.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that is part of what I am documenting - what options they have.  They have low-level code that they want to make use of.  The C# they write is just to plug into the infrastructure.  They will be responsible for calling their low-level functions.  They may have a String that they are iterating through, for example, and calling the function with each character.  I'm just documenting how to make use of the different types their C++ code may require.

Comment: You aren't answering. What C# type do you imagine mapping to a C++ ANSI `char` on Windows? It isn't something that happens. Sure C# `byte` maps to C++ `unsigned char` but that's quite different. No text encoding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, again, according to the Microsoft documentation, System.Char maps to **both** `char` and `wchar_t`.  I think we are both asking the same question.  I don't really see how the one type can map to both native types.  Except for the use of the `Charset=...` attribute (which wasn't mentioned in the Microsoft doc I mentioned).

Comment: We already did `CharSet` didn't we? What you can't do is give a credible use case for this. There likely isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t*` is basically a `String` and it's the same as `LPWSTR`. For the method `doSomethingElse`, I would say either this:

```
[DllImport("MyLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern Int32 doSomethingElse(StringBuilder builder);
```

or this:

```
[DllImport("MyLib.dll")]
internal static extern Int32 doSomethingElse([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String str);
```

For what concerns the method `doSomething`, I'm kinda uncertain. I mean, it asks for a single `char`, and it's weird. A `byte` would not be the same thing and I'm wondering if your declaration is correct.

Comment: OK.  That works for an array of `wchar_t`, I suppose.  How about a single `wchar_t` as a parameter?

Comment: First example would match `wchar_t**`. That's wrong then. `wchar_t*` is not very similar to `LPWSTR`. It is identical. And who says the text is coming from callee to caller?

Comment: Yeah well you know, if the OP doesn't write the function all I can do is going for a guess.

Comment: No. We don't guess. We wait until the question is clear. You have enough rep here to know that.